# Solr Search - Adding taxonomy to Search results

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm using the 'Solr Search' module ( not Apache solr search ) .

What I need to do is return results that have a taxonomy term relationship.

In my search indexes 'fields'  I have the taxonomy I want 'Keywords'  selected. The type for this is 'Taxonomy term'  .  I have also added 'Keywords » Name' through 'Add Related Fields'  .  This is type 'Fulltext'  and after reindexing and saving this field appears in views/search/page / search ‘full text’ / Searched fields.

However when I search for a keyword through the exposed filter the results are not being returned. They can however been seen in Facets.

Any idea what I might be missing.

Comment: When you said Solr Search you mean search api ? Did you re-index your content ? Usually when I'm using Search api module and I make changes I need to re-index my content in order to see the changes.

Comment: Hi. Yeah I had been re indexing. It might have been something obvious tho as I rebuilt the search view and this worked fine.

Comment: Common mistakes it happen to me all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I rebuilt the view and this time it worked fine.